# MYSQL SELECT repeatable fields into columns

Tags: mysql, subquery, pivot, pivot-table

I'm not sure whether I have to make a pivot table or some sub-queries to get the desired result, but this is the table I have:

```
asset_id    id       title           title_type
34           1       episode 1       5
34           2       TNS             4
34           3       WXPR            3
35           4       episode 57      5
35           5       BLSH            4
35           6       WXRE            3
36           7       episode 56      5
36           8       BLSH            4
36           9       WXRE            3
```

But this is what I want. Each title_type in it's own column and WHERE title with title_type 4 = BLSH.  So like this:

```
asset id       title_type 5     title_type 4    title_type 3 
35             episode 56       BLSH            WXRE
36             episode 57       BLSH            WXRE
```

Comment: how many different title types are there? are they subject to change any time? how flexible must your query be? must the query automagically adapt when a new title type is added?

Comment: Hi!  Right now, I only use title types: 3,4, and 5.  I don't foresee a time when that would change. And although the titles may change (the spelling or something like that), the title_type associated with that title would always stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real fix of course is to change your database structure ;-)

However, you may use JOINs to get the desired data. In my example there is no subselect involved:

```
SELECT 
  o.asset_id, 
  /* select the data from the self-joins */
  `5`.title AS title_type_5,
  `4`.title AS title_type_4,
  `3`.title AS title_type_3
FROM 
  foo o
/* use self-joins to combine data of multiple rows in a single row */
LEFT JOIN foo `3` ON `3`.title_type = 3 AND `3`.asset_id = o.asset_id
LEFT JOIN foo `4` ON `4`.title_type = 4 AND `4`.asset_id = o.asset_id
LEFT JOIN foo `5` ON `5`.title_type = 5 AND `5`.asset_id = o.asset_id
WHERE 
  o.title_type = "4" 
  AND o.title = "BLSH"
```

[Try my example on SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0a95/9)

Comment: Works!  I may have over simplified the table to illustrate the problem  , but any insight on how to make a better structure would be greatly apprciated!  Thanks a bunch!